# Mock alert with fn() from another function

Tags: jestjs

I have a file1.js with a function that fires up alert():
file1.js

```js
export function test(value){
  alert(value); //string
}
```

file1.test.js:

```js
import { test } from "./test";
...
it("returns value", () => {
    
  window.alert = jest.fn();
  test(10);
  expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith("10");
});
```

Could someone point me out how to get the alert called?

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is mocking a function, which you can view how to do in this link [here](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/mock-function-api.html).
When you mock a function, you're essentially obtaining the instance(s) of the said functions. You may also find that using the `jest.spyOn()` function will also help too and more or less does the same thing.

Another thing to note is that you're testing **what** the function does, which is how I undergo writing my unit tests. This pattern is known as *AAA (Arrange, Act, Assert)* which you should read up on in this [link](https://medium.com/xebia-engineering/unit-testing-aaa-pattern-ab1c08737d53).

-Ehsan

Comment: You know. I think everything is working fine, but I'm using codesandbox and I think it makes my test failed somehow.

Answer (score 0):

In Codesandbox instead of `alert()` it should be `window.alert()`